# Extracting files from res folder in Executable JAR (txt files to be specific)

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I would like to ask if its possible to put text files into my jar, I use them to make my map in my game, but users can get Highscores. now I want to save the Highscores with the map, so I have to save the map on the user their PC. Is there any way how I could do this? I've searched the internet for some ideas but I could not find anything that even came close to what I've wanted. I only had 3/4th of a year java so I don't know much about these things, everything that happens outside the debug of eclipse are problems for me(files are mainly one of those things, null exceptions, etc).

The main question now.

Is it possible to do? If yes, do you have any terms I could search on, or some sites/guides/tutorials? If no, is there any other way how I could save the highscores?

EDIT:
to make clear

Can I get the text file (the text inside the file) to be extracted to a different file in like the home directory of my game (where I save the settings and stuff) the basic maps are inside the jar file, so I want them to be extracted on the first start-up of the program

Greetings Carolien

Comment: I dont think i get your question clearly . Is your question on 

a ) How to add text files to jar or 
b ) Read from the text files added to the jar . 

I believe you want to do both ? 

Check [Java Jar file - how to read a file from a Jar file](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/read-text-file-from-jar-file) . It should give you some leads . Maybe if it isnt useful you may comment back .

Comment: my question is, can i get the text file (the text inside the file) to be extracted to a different file in like the home directory of my game (where i save the settings and stuff) the basic maps are inside the jar file, so i want them to be extracted on the first startup of the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "extracted to a different file in like the home directory of my game (where i save the settings and stuff) the basic maps are inside the jar file, so i want them to be extracted on the first startup of the program"

You can get the URL by using `getClass().getResource()`

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/res/myfile.txt");
```

Then create a File object from the URI of the URL

```
File file = new File(url.toURI());
```

Then just perform your normal file operations.

```
if (file.renameTo(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\" + file.getName()))) {
    System.out.println("File is moved successful!");
} else {
    System.out.println("File is failed to move!");
}
```

Assuming your file structure is like below, it should work fine

```
ProjectRoot
         src
            res
               myfile.txt
```

---

Note: the above is moving the entire file. If you want to extract just the data inside the file, then you can simple use

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/myfile.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

The just do normal IO operation with the `reader`. See [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-move-file-to-another-directory-in-java/) for help with writing the file.